# Kafka Streams and DLQ producer

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm designing the error handling in our stream application and I would like to use DLQ approach. I found couple information how to use DLQ producer directly from DSL functions, but is it possible to use Processor API?

To use processor API I'll need to implement several Transformer<>, e.g:

```
class FilterErrorHandler<K, V> extends AbstractErrorHandler<K, V, KeyValue<K, V>> {

    final Predicate<K, V> predicate;
    final boolean filterNot;

    FilterErrorHandler(Predicate<K, V> predicate, boolean filterNot) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.filterNot = filterNot;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<K, V> transform(K k, V v) {
        try {

            if (filterNot ^ predicate.test(k, v)) {
                return KeyValue.pair(k, v);
            }

            return null;
        } catch (StreamProcessingException e) {

            // e.getErrorContext();
            // set error headers
            // context().headers();

            log.error("Filter predicate: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            context().forward(k, v, To.child("ERROR_HANDLING_SINK"));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In above code my "DLQ producer" is a forward() method. Child processor is just a sink added in topology:

```
topology.addSink("ERROR_HANDLING)SINK", keySerde, valueSerde)
```

The problem is that I'll need to implement error handles for all functions like map, flatMap, etc.

Is there simpler solution ?

This error handling should handle also business errors, I know about deserialization/production error handlers, but in this case I would like to implement something like "dynamic branch" .